# How to build a mixed-ANCOVA-model with lme()?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, assumptions, ancova

I want to perform a split-plot ANCOVA in R. I try to test, whether the assignment to one group (of two; between-subject factor) has an effect on a performance task (measured 5 times during the experiment; within-subject factor). Additionally, I want to control for baseline differences and therefore use the first time of the performance task as a covariate.
I discovered the function anova_test() of the package rstatix. For my analysis, the formula would look like this:

```
res.aov <- rstatix :: anova_test(data = data_myVOI, dv = value_dp, wid = participant,  between = group, within = time, covariate = bs_covariate, type = 3)
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

Output of the anova_test-model:

ANOVA Table (type III tests)

```
         Effect   DFn  DFd   F    p p<.05        ges
     bs_covariate   1  71 24.551 4.74e-06     * 0.165
            group   2  71  0.241 7.86e-01       0.004
             time   3 213  2.080 1.04e-01       0.012
bs_covariate:time   3 213  1.238 2.97e-01       0.007
       group:time   6 213  1.154 3.32e-01       0.014
```

Unfortunately, I can not figure out a way to check all the assumptions necessary (especially these, involving residuals or other regression parameters e.g. normality of residuals, homogeneity of regression slopes) with the anova_test()-function.  Hence, I tried to build a regression model, hoping that I would find the right formula and be able to use the calculated residuals to check the assumptions. So far, I used the lme()-function to build the model:

```
model <- lme(value_dp ~ bs_covariate + group + time + bs_covariate*time + group*time, random=~1|participant, data = data_myVOI)
anova(model)
```

Output of the lme-model:

```
          Effect numDF denDF  F-value p-value
      Intercept     1   213 636.4947  <.0001
          group     2    71   0.4941  0.6122
   bs_covariate     1    71  24.5506  <.0001
           time     3   213   7.9788  <.0001
bs_covariate:time   3   213   1.0063  0.3909
       group:time   6   213   1.1539  0.3324
```

As you can see, the lme-model produces basically the same F-values for group and group-time-interaction as the anova_test-model. Nevertheless the values for the covariate and covariate-time-interaction are slightly different between the models and the time-factor varies a lot.
I expect the lme-model to be wrong, so I am wondering:

1. How can I improve the lme-model?
2. Or is there a simpler solution to check the assumptions e.g. with the rstatix-package?
   I would be grateful for any assistance!